# How to add class to an element if clicked on another?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

So I've been trying to expand the header tag by adding a class every time a specific element was clicked, and then remove the class if the element isn't clicked anymore. I've already tried various methods, such as:

```
if($('element').data('clicked')){
   $('otherelement').addClass('class');

} else {
   $('otherelement').removeClass('class');
}
```

The code above worked, though the class stayed, and no matter where I clicked from there on, it stayed.

My code now looks like this:

```js
var isClicked = false;


$('ul.nav-main-list.sec>.nav-main-item').click(function() {
  isClicked = true;
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  if (isClicked) {
    $('header').addClass('nav-expand');
  } else {
    $('header').removeClass('nav-expand');
  }
});
```

```css
.main-header{
  height: 50px;
  background-color: grey;
}

.nav-expand{
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!Doctype html>
<html>

  <head>

  </head>

  <body>
    <header class="main-header">
      <nav id="nav-main">
        <ul class="nav-main-list prem">
          <li class="nav-main-item">
            <a class="nav-main-link" href="#">Click</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-main-item">
            <ul class="nav-main-list sec">
              <li class="nav-main-item">
                <a class="nav-main-link" href="#">Click2</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>

    </header>
  </body>

</html>
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work, and I would be very pleased if someone could help me out.

Notice: The code I have shown you isn't where the actual problem is, and rather just an example of my problem. Please understand that I would rather not show my real code as it is the company I work for. If you don't understand, or miss more code, just leave a comment, and I'll try to do my best to make it understandable.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `The code I have shown you isn't where the actual problem is`. It would be better if you could provide the actual code that is not working.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I've tried to make the example as authentic as possible in comparison to the "real" code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern you're using to handle clicks isn't right. You need to actually update the DOM within the event handler function, not just set the boolean value as that's only evaluated in your `if` condition when the page loads. The `click` handler itself also needs to be placed within the document.ready handler. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('ul.nav-main-list.sec > .nav-main-item').click(function() {
    $('header').toggleClass('nav-expand');
  });
});
```

```css
.main-header {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: grey;
}

.nav-expand {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="main-header">
  <nav id="nav-main">
    <ul class="nav-main-list prem">
      <li class="nav-main-item">
        <a class="nav-main-link" href="#">Click</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-main-item">
        <ul class="nav-main-list sec">
          <li class="nav-main-item">
            <a class="nav-main-link" href="#">Click2</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Sounds right and feels right, but every time I click on the link, it expands the header just for a second, and then goes back to it's original form.

Comment: In which case there's another underlying problem somewhere in your code which isn't in the question. I would assume from that behaviour it's to do with an event handler on a parent element which is caught when the event bubbles up the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is prevent the event from propagating and do not need the global variable, just toggle the class.  When you do not propagate, it bubbles up and you get multiple handlers fired.

```js
$('.nav-main-item').on('click', function(even) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  $('.main-header').toggleClass('nav-expand');
});

$('.main-header').toggleClass('nav-expand', false);
```

```css
.main-header {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #DDDDDD;
}

.nav-expand {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #DDDD77;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<header class="main-header">
  <nav id="nav-main">
    <ul class="nav-main-list prem">
      <li class="nav-main-item">
        <a class="nav-main-link" href="#">Click</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-main-item">
        <ul class="nav-main-list sec">
          <li class="nav-main-item">
            <a class="nav-main-link" href="#">Click2</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```